# useRef store value and display value in DOM [React]

Tags: reactjs

Because this component changes frequently, I decided to use `useRef` to store values (for example, a counter). On an event (such as onclick), the log shows that the number did increment by 1 each time the button was clicked, but the value isn't updated on the screen (inside the div). It's showing `0`. What am I missing here?

Intended output: on click button, `add()` increases `counter`, and display value in `<div>`.

```js
const counter = useRef(0);

function add() {
  counter.current += 1;
  console.log(counter.current); // this shows that the number did increment 
}

return (
  <div>
    <div>{counter.current}</div> {/* this shows '0' */}
    <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>
  </div>
);
```

Comment: use `useState` in this case

Comment: Why not use `useState`?

Comment: I am interacting this variable in third party library listener functions. These libraries loads on page load, and receiving events from javascript listener.

Comment: with your approach react dosent know there is a change to be rerender the content

Comment: To see the new value the component must be updated, this only happens when the state is updated or a passed prop has a new value. For this use `useState` just the above comments say

Comment: If you want to display the change on every button click, you must update the state, a reference won't help you.

Comment: Thanks everyone for quick inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you stated in the comments:

> I am interacting with this variable in third party library listener functions. These libraries loads on page load, and receiving events from javascript listener.

Means that you want to render component on 3rd party reference change, usually you mock a render like so:

```
const reducer = p => !p;

const App = () => {
  const counter = useRef(0);
  const [, render] = useReducer(reducer, false);

  function add() {
    // Some 3rd party ref
    counter.current += 1;

    // Render and update the UI
    render();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{counter.current}</div>
      <button onClick={() => add()}>Add</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit exciting-architecture-fu0s6]

Answer (score 0):

read the [doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

> Keep in mind that useRef doesn’t notify you when its content changes. Mutating the .current property doesn’t cause a re-render. If you want to run some code when React attaches or detaches a ref to a DOM node, you may want to use a callback ref instead.

using the `useState` is the best thing in our case